# How does this static code work?

Tags: java

Code:

```
public static void main ( String[] args){
      String a = new String("Hello");
      String b = " pardner.";
      System.out.println(a+b);
      System.out.println("a.equals(\"Hello\") --> " + (a.equals("Hello")));
      System.out.println("a --> " + a);
}

static {
      try {
          Field value = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
          value.setAccessible(true);
          value.set("Hello", value.get("Howdy"));
      } catch (Exception e) { }
}
```

Result:

```
Howdy pardner.
a.equals("Hello") --> true
a --> Howdy
```

How does this code change "Hello" to "Howdy" when printing?

Comment: It uses reflection to replace each string which is "Hello" with "Howdy".

Comment: That's *really* interesting! Notice what happens if you make `String a` *final*. It must be some form of compiler optimization.

Comment: Related : [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8086065/1391249), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20036436/1391249)

Answer (score 9):

First, [`String` literals composed of the same characters resolve to the same instance.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) So in

```
String one = "hello";
String two = "hello";
```

both variables are referring to the same object.

Second, [`static` initializer blocks are executed when a class is first loaded (and initialized)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7). This occurs before any class methods are invoked, ie. before `main`.

[Third, your Java version's implementation of `String`, presumably, uses a `char\[\]` field to store the string of characters. This field is named `value`.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/String.java#String.0value)

You're [using reflection to retrieve](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get-java.lang.Object-) this `char[]` for the `String` object referenced by the `String` literal `"Howdy"`.

```
Field value = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
...
value.get("Howdy")
```

and assigning it to the `char[]` field of the `String` object referenced by the `String` literal `"Hello"`

```
value.set("Hello", value.get("Howdy"));
```

Now, when your `main` method executes

```
String a = new String("Hello");
```

the `String` literal `"Hello"` is referencing the same object for which you set the `char[]` field previously. This `char[]` contains the characters `'H'`, `'o'`, `'w'`, `'d'`, and `'y'` since it was taken from the `String` object referenced by the literal `"Howdy"`.

These characters are copied into a **new** `String` object created here

```
String a = new String("Hello");
```

Answer (score 8):

The first thing that happens is your `static` block executes. By reflection, it changes the value of `String a` to `"Howdy"` (actually it changes the `String` `"Hello"` to `"Howdy"` but that has the same effect). However, you get

```
a.equals("Hello") --> true
```

because the compiler has already replaced the value with `true`. I ran `javap -v` and got

```
31: ldc           #75                 // String a.equals(\"Hello\") --> true
```

So that is exactly what has happened. As I noted in the comments, if you change `String a` to

```
final String a = "Hello";
```

The last line changes to

```
a --> Hello
```

for the same reason.

Comment: I'm not seeing the `final` behavior as you describe it in Java 7.

Comment: @Makoto  I tested with Java 8. Note, I did have to use `final String a = "Hello";` not `final String a = new String("Hello");`

Comment: I think a `String` literal will exhibit different behaviour to using the constructor.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html

*public void set(Object obj, Object value)*

> Sets the field represented by this Field object on the specified
>   object argument to the specified new value. The new value is
>   automatically unwrapped if the underlying field has a primitive type.

*public get(Object obj)*

> Returns the value of the field represented by this Field, on the
>   specified object.

Your static block is executed in first.

All occurrences of String containing "Hello" are replaced by the String "Howdy" by reflection before the `main()` execution.

"Hello" and "Howdy" are referring to the same object. This is why `s.equals("Hello")` outputs true
`System.out.println(a.equals("Howdy"));` would also output `true`.

Take a look to the exact execution process:
[image]